# Can I peek at input gestures from within android.view.View.onDraw()?

Tags: android, ondraw

I have a lengthy onDraw operation in a custom-drawing Android view, as a consequence of which scrolling and scaling operations are horribly user-unfriendly.

Fixing the lengthy onDraw is the real solution (I'm working on it but it will take some time); in the meantime it would be useful to peek at user gestures while drawing, in order to abbreviate onDraw and show only a wireframe to help with the scroll and scale operations.  This approach works nicely by setting a wireframe-only flag within onScroll, onScale, and onScaleBegin (from various interfaces), but with onScaleEnd (for example) I need to commit and say, "Go ahead and draw it all."  Then the system draws the whole darn thing before finally taking note of any additional attempts to scroll or scale.

If I could peek at the event queue from within onDraw, I could drop back into wireframe mode and let the user complete the scroll or scale.

Is that possible?

-- Bob

[One day after asking the original question:] Although I'm still curious about the answer to the question (Can one peek into the event queue while drawing?), I talked with a colleague and worked out a decent solution to the main problem (the lengthy draw operation).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to peek at the incoming messages by instantiating a `Handler()` with a Looper from the main thread but `handleMessage()` was never invoked. I suspect that any message related to pointer events were removed from the `MessageQueue` associated with the `Looper`. Either that or maybe the `Message` was received by a Handler associated with an I/O thread and translated to a `MotionEvent` that was then dispatched on the main thread in `onMotionEvent()` etc.

Android View.java has a final method that dispatches the corresponding MotionEvent but this method is final and cannot be looked at.

```
 /**
     * Dispatch a pointer event.
     * <p>
     * Dispatches touch related pointer events to {@link #onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)} and all
     * other events to {@link #onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent)}.  This separation of concerns
     * reinforces the invariant that {@link #onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)} is really about touches
     * and should not be expected to handle other pointing device features.
     * </p>
     *
     * @param event The motion event to be dispatched.
     * @return True if the event was handled by the view, false otherwise.
     * @hide
     */
    public final boolean dispatchPointerEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.isTouchEvent()) {
            return dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        } else {
            return dispatchGenericMotionEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

If I/O events are processed on a separate thread from the main thread, I don't think it's possible to peek at the MessageQueue for the thread that processes the I/O events.

If it were possible then that would likely solve the problem of peeking at pending motion events.